# Can't install .net 3.5 sp1 on windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, 64-bit, .net-3.5

I am trying to install subtext via the Web Platform Installer on my Windows server 2008 VPS.

To install it I need the .net framework version 3.5 SP1. It actually fails definetly each time I try, so I tried to install the SP1 manually. I failed with the error message :

```
[11/30/09,02:40:01] Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0SP1 (x64) (CBS): [2] Error: Installation failed for component Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0SP1 (x64) (CBS). MSI returned error code -2147467262
[11/30/09,02:40:05] WapUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0SP1 (x64) (CBS) is not installed.
```

When I tried to install the .net 2.0 SP1 x64 it says that it is not supported by vista (?!). I tried to clean up every .net version of my server using the cleanup tool and then install the 3.5sp1 back (and even 2.0sp1) both failed with same error codes.

I am not able to use the Windows update since it is a virtuozzo VPS (and it is said that if I use Windows update it will break my VPS because updates are streamlined by Virtuozzo... ) but the windows update service is started.

Any hints on solving this issue ?

[edit]

Currently the versions installed are :

- .Net 2.0.50727.1434
- .Net 3.0.4506.648

[edit-2]
Here is a screenshot of my server manager:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The .NET Framework 3.0 is included in the base installation for Server 2008.  However, it's a "**Feature**" that must be enabled in **Server Manager**.  Once the feature is enabled, Windows Update should pick up the additional patches and service packs for it.

Comment: Already there... I need the 3.5 SP1.

Comment: I added a picture of the server manager ...

Comment: Without spinning up a new 2008 VM, I'm not really sure then.  Usually we let Windows Update take care of installing additional .NET pieces.  But I don't know whether 3.5 is considered critical or optional.

Answer (score 0):

The installer is trying to connect to the internet. Try Microsoft. NET Framework 3.5 Service pack 1 (Full Package) http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25150